# Liferay Spring Portlet EDIT Mode not visible

Tags: spring, liferay, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc

we have a liferay 6.1 portlet that has an edit mode. Sadly that edit mode is not visible - there is no icon, nothing that could be clicked.

On my local developer machine I first couldn´t see it, too and had to restart my server in order to do so. After the restart the EDIT mode was visible.

Now I try to bring the portlet, including the EDIT mode, to our life system and again ... the EDIT mode is not visible. Since I do not dare to restart the server ... is there any way to refresh the portlet ?

Comment: Have you included the `<portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>` in `<supports>` of your `portlet.xml`?

Comment: Yes I added it to the portlet.xml file

Comment: Is it a plugin portlet? 1. If yes, then you can just cut your portlet from container (Tomcat) and wait for `portlet unregistered successfully` message in console, paste it again and the portlet will be registered again without the need of restarting your server.

Comment: 2. Liferay support hot deployment of plugins, therefore if you will deploy your plugin's `war` file again, it will update it on the fly.

Comment: Ok that sounds good. Will do this and then let you know.

Comment: didn´t work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server is partly corrupt:

It needed a full restart